# Creating a new field from a function based on 2 vectors from a DataFrame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, cosine-similarity

I have a DataFrame and would like to create a new field based on a calculation using a function that takes 2 vectors taken from a row of a DataFrame.

For example, I have data that looks like this;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "B": [6,7,8,9,10],
    "C": [7,8,1,9,10],
    "D": [2,3,4,5,6],
 })
```

and I want to calculate the `cosine_similarity` of `[A,B].[C,D]` on a row by row basis and then output the result as a new column `E`

The function I have is as follows;

```
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise as pw

def similarity(Vec1, Vec2):
    return pw.cosine_similarity(Vec1,Vec2)
```

I am looking at using the `map` and `lambda` functions and currently have the following. The issue here is that this is calculating the cosine similarity down a column, rather than across. Really I would like to be able to do this using indexing so I can choose the fields I need and in case the number of fields gets very large!

```
df['E'] = map(lambda x,y : similarity(x,y), df.iloc[:,2:], df.iloc[:,:2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise as pw

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "B": [6,7,8,9,10],
    "C": [7,8,1,9,10],
    "D": [2,3,4,5,6],
 })

df['E'] = df.apply(lambda row: pw.cosine_similarity(np.array([row['A'], row['B']]),
                   np.array([row['C'], row['D']]))[0][0], axis=1)

#    A   B   C  D         E
# 0  1   6   7  2  0.429057
# 1  2   7   8  3  0.594843
# 2  3   8   1  4  0.993533
# 3  4   9   9  5  0.798815
# 4  5  10  10  6  0.843661
```

A more easily extendible solution:

```
df['E'] = [pw.cosine_similarity(i, j)[0][0] for i, j in \
           zip(df[df.columns[:2]].values, df[df.columns[2:]].values)]
```

Functional alternative:

```
df['E'] = list(map(lambda i, j: pw.cosine_similarity(i, j)[0][0],
                   df[df.columns[:2]].values,
                   df[df.columns[2:]].values))
```

Comment: This is great but really I would like to be able to do this using indexing. What if the number of fields I need to include in the cosine similarity gets very large?

Comment: The extendable solution does the job but I am looking for a more general way of applying a function like the one in my question to 2 vectors that come from a DataFrame :)

Comment: Thanks! Almost similar to what I had. I am interested, what are the `[0][0]` for?

Comment: I'm not sure why but the output of the `pw.cosine_similarity` function is a vector of shape / format `[[23.4121]]`, so to extract the number part I take the first element of the first element.

Comment: Ahh yes! I noticed that too. Makes sense! Thanks!